# Eclipse RustDT not working

Tags: eclipse

Professional embedded C programmer here. I really like Rust a great deal, and have been trying to learn the language. I'd really like to start using Eclipse as an IDE for Rust, but I can't get even the simplest programs to execute. I get this error: "No launch executable specified by the Build Target." Any clues?